# Функция в нативном php(без использования бибилиотек), которая проверяет корректность структуры тегов html документа

Tags: php, html

Написать функцию, которая на входе принимает массив из открывающихся или закрывающихся тегов и возвращает результат корректности:  т.е. является ли принятая функцией последовательность тегов структурой корректного HTML документа. Например, последовательность `“<a>”, “<div>”, “</div>”, “</a>”, “<span>”, “</span>”` - корректная структура, а последовательность `“<a>”, “<div>”, ”</a>”`- некорректная структура.
Необходимо использовать нативный php без использования библиотек.

Из идей только проверка на наличии / в массиве. Если их ровно половина элементов, то корректно, если нет-то нет. Но это не совсем то, что нужно.

```
$x = array('<a>', '<div>', '</div>', '</a>', '<span>', '</span>');
$n=count($x);

$comma_separated=implode(",",$x);

foreach (count_chars($comma_separated, 1) as $i => $val) {
    if (chr($i)=='/'){
        $m=$val;
    echo "\"" , chr($i) , "\" встречается в строке $val раз(а).\n";
    }
 }

 if ($m==$n/2){
    echo "This document is valid!\n"; 
} 
else { 
    echo "This document is invalid!\n";   
}
```

Comment: На работу устраиваться тоже все вместе пойдем?

Comment: читать про *стек*

Comment: Можете создать массив. Открывающие теги добавлять методом `array_push()`, а на закрытие `array_pop()`. После чего сравнить результат array_pop() - с текущим элементом массива и в случае не эквивалентности - ошибка

Comment: получилось в итоге?

Answer (score 1):

```
function check($input){
    $open = array();  // Создаем масив для открывающихся тегов

    foreach ($input as $item){
        if (strpos($item, '/') === false){ //Проверяем или тег открывающийся
            $open[] = $item; // Если открывающийся добавляем его в масив
        } else{
            $item_close = array_pop($open); // Если тег закрывающийся берем последний елемент масива $open
            $check_tag = str_replace("/", "", $item); // Трансформируем закрывающийся тег в открывающийся
            if($item_close != $check_tag){ // Проверяем совпадают ли теги
                return 'This document is invalid!\n'; // Если не совпали масив не валиден
            }
        }
    }
    if(sizeof($open) == 0){  //Проверяем масив если он пуст то значит он валидный
        return 'This document is valid!\n';
    } else{
        return 'This document is invalid!\n';
    }
}

$test = array('<a>', '<div>', '</div>', '</a>');
echo check($test);
```

Comment: Я не знаю что здесь смешнее - использование рекурсии или сама возможность  умудриться зафейлить такую примитивную задачу

Comment: Покажите правильное решение

Comment: Корректный ответ уже дан в комментариях к вопросу

Comment: Если не сложно можите код функции написать чтобы понять как правильно делать.

Comment: Это тестовое задание и автор вопроса должен сделать его сам.

Comment: Да я понимаю, мне чисто для своего так сказать развития. Возможно через несколько дней когда для автора ответ уже будет не актуален.

Comment: Я думаю что стоит все-таки поработать над вопросом самостоятельно. Это гораздо полезнее для развития чем увидеть готовый результат

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119053/discussion-between-dmitriy-kondratiuk-and-).

Comment: Добавил вариант без рекрусии. Подозреваю что можно еще както спростить, если да то подскажите как.

Comment: ну ведь в комментарии четко написано, чем пользоваться. то что сейчас - это ужас

Comment: $test = array('<a>','<a>', '<div>','</a>', '</div>', '</a>');

Comment: Поиски истины продолжаются ))